# sqlalchemy orm mysql dataframe create using two databases

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE+URI'] = \
        "mariadb+mariadbconnector://harold:password@localhost:3306/movie?charset=utf8mb4"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = \
        {'two' : "mariadb+mariadbconnector://harold:password@localhost:3306 /tvshow?charset=utf8mb4"}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "movie"
    movie_id = Column(VARCHAR(length=25), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(VARCHAR(length=255), nullable=False)
    series_id = Column(VARCHAR(length=25), nullable=False)
    rel_date = Column(VARCHAR(length=25), nullable=False)

class TVShow(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'two'
    __tablename__ = "tvshow"
    tv_id = Column(VARCHAR(length=25), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(length=255), nullable=False)
    seasons = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)
    episodes = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)

def set_df():
    main1_df = pd.read_sql_table('movie', engine1)
    main2_df = pd.read_sql_table('tvshow', engine2)
```

So, how do I specify which database for the con/engine? I need to make dataframe from both tables.

I have tried using complete sqlalchemy_database_uri, did not work.
Tried using two for second database, did not work. Do I have to make engines? How?

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL/MariaDB, "database" and "schema" mean the same thing, so if both databases are on the same server we can just use `schema=` to specify the database name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

# make default database some other one (just for illustration)
engine = sa.create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost:3307/mydb", echo=True)

main1_df = pd.read_sql_table("movie", engine, schema="movie")
"""
SELECT movie.movie.id, … FROM movie.movie
"""

main2_df = pd.read_sql_table("tvshow", engine, schema="tvshow")
"""
SELECT tvshow.tvshow.id, … FROM tvshow.tvshow
"""
```

Comment: So, how does the query work??  result = session.query(movie.Movie).all() would return all for the Movie table as result?? Or do I need to do .to_html before sending to html as in render_template('index.html', data=[main_df.to_html]